# IE11 User-Agent - Wrong one when pointing towards localhost - Right one when going towards my PC name?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, http-headers, user-agent, internet-explorer-11

I am using internet explorer 11.0.9600.16438

I am hosing my website locally. When I go to **localhost/myWebSite/Default.aspx** I get the following User-Agent information:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like MyCompanyName

When I however go to **myComputerName/myWebSite/Default.aspx** i get the following User-Agent information:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)

(This is the correct one because the website sets IE to go towards Document mode 8)

I use this User-Agent information to determine if .NET is installed etc. on a customers computer. I need the localhost one to show the correct User-Agent information. Why does it differ? This was not a problem in IE10 as far as I know.

Comment: Does your corporate policy put IE into compatability mode for Intranet sites?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the terrible setting in IE to display intranet sites in "Compatibility mode". To turn it off check out the following link:

http://support.myeasyprojects.net/KB/a210/how-to-turn-off-the-compatibility-view-mode-in-ie-8-ie-9.aspx