# Strange user agent when debugging MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, internet-explorer-11, user-agent

I couldn't find any relevant post about this mysterious behaviour anywhere else so excuse me if there's an obvious answer.

I am testing an application in various browsers and IE 11 has some strange behaviour.

When I visit a site that tells me my user agent I get:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Which is standard for IE11.

However when I run my application the user agent is different only on IE11.
I tried debugging the application on IE11 by adding in Global.asax:

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest()
  {
      var ua1 = Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
      var ua2 = Request.UserAgent;
  }
```

Both of them show:

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
```

Chrome shows the same on both cases but IE 11 shows different user agents depending whether I am in my application or any other tab. So my application seems to affect the user agent somehow but only when viewing it with IE11.

Can someone explain this and tell me how to get the same user agent even via my application? Any idea why this is happening?

Ideally I want when debugging to get the expected user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you by any chance have the F12 Developer Tools window open and the browser emulation set to IE7, or the user agent spoofing set to Internet Explorer 7?

You can find it in the `Emulation` tab of the tool.

Alternatively, if that is not set, have you checked if IE is running in "Compatibility Mode" - as it may be set to do this for intranet sites. If so, this question is a likely duplicate of:

[IE11 User-Agent - Wrong one when pointing towards localhost - Right one when going towards my PC name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494198/ie11-user-agent-wrong-one-when-pointing-towards-localhost-right-one-when-goi?rq=1)

and also:

[IE 11 sends different User-Agent header to different subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005832/ie-11-sends-different-user-agent-header-to-different-subdomains?rq=1)

Comment: The problem was that IE was configured to render all intranet sites in Compatibility View. This helped. Thanks